# How to detect if URL location is on this page and any other sub-folders of same domain

Tags: javascript, url

As the title said. But here what I mean.

say I am on www.google.com/someRandomFolder/dfsjfkdjff.html

and I got a code like this

```
if(location == "www.google.com/*") {
   Execute some Code
}
```

It will execute. The "*" is there to say anything after www.google.com/ it will run. As long as the first part is that.

So is there anyway to accomplish this? Cause I got a page that the URL will change at the end because it passes variables in the URL. So I can't have it a set location for it to work.

If I didn't explain it will just leave a comment below and I will try to elaborate.

EDIT:
You know how in Java or C++ you can either get that single component of a package that you need by doing awt.color.red; or you can just get the whole package by doing awt.*; So basically I want to do the same thing you can declare to get the whole package, but with a webpage location.

Cause I will have http://www.someWebpage.com/?id=54
and the "id" will not always been 54 so I can not use this code

```
if(location == "http://www.someWebpage.com/?id=54") {
   Execute some Code
}
```

Because what if it is http://www.someWebpage.com/?id=25 instead? It will not execute that code anymore. I could always just use substr(x,endX) to accomplish what I want, but I want to know if there is a better way of doing so.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I edited it, I hope I made more sense!

Comment: `window.location.hostname === "www.google.com"`

Comment: Okay, thank you!!! I couldn't find that anywhere when I googled. You should go post it as an answer so I can vote it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location` is basically an instance of a class that stores information about your current location. It has a variety of properties and methods for manipulating and retrieving data about your page's url.

For example, if you type `window.location` into your console, you'll get something like this:

```
Location {replace: function, assign: function, ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList, origin: "https://developer.mozilla.org", hash: ""…}
ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList
assign: function () { [native code] }
hash: ""
host: "developer.mozilla.org"
hostname: "developer.mozilla.org"
href: "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location"
origin: "https://developer.mozilla.org"
pathname: "/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location"
port: ""
protocol: "https:"
reload: function reload() { [native code] }
replace: function () { [native code] }
search: ""
toString: function toString() { [native code] }
valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }
__proto__: Location
```

Then all you have to do is pick the property that has the information you want. In your case, you want to check if the hostname is correct, so you'd access `window.location.hostname`.

Read more about window.location [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)